# Phpunit - How add another object type to mocking object

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I need to add Mailable type to my mocked ActivationMail. Maybe you have better idea to mock my `ActivationMail` class?
Tested class:

```
class MailService
{
    public function sendActivationEmail(User $user): void
    {
        $this->sendEmail(new ActivationMail($user));
    }

    //content

    protected function sendEmail(Mailable $mailable): void
    {
        //content
    }
}
```

ActivationMail:

```
class ActivationMail extends Mailable{}
```

Do you have idea how can I test it?
 
My test:

```
public function test_sendActivationEmail()
{
    $user = Mockery::mock(User::class);
    $mailable = Mockery::mock(Mailable::class);

    Mockery::mock('overload:App\Mail\ActivationMail');

    $mailService = new MailService();
    $mailService->sendActivationEmail($user);
}
```

And my error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Services\MailService::sendEmail()
>   must be an instance of Illuminate\Mail\Mailable, instance of
>   App\Mail\ActivationMail given